# Why does React not use a script tag?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why don't we have to put a script tag into the index.html when using the creat-react-app package?

Comment: It does use a script tag, that's one of the things CRA does for you - look in the build outputs instead of the input template.

Answer (score 4):

#### It's a template

The file `/public/index.html`, which you would edit during development, is only a template.

In the default installation of [`create-react-app`](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) this is also stated in a comment inside of that [`index.html` template](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/main/packages/cra-template/template/public/index.html):

```html
<!--
  This HTML file is a template.
  If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

  You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
  The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.
  
  [...]
-->
```

#### The "real" index.html

The final `index.html` file is created in the build step.

I.e. if you run:

```
node ./node_modules/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts.js build
```

then `react-scripts.js` will create all the final `.html` and `.js` files based on the template and
all your setups and components, and links them together properly.

As a result, the final files are created inside of a new folder, e.g. `/build`, where you can also find the
final `/build/index.html`, including the automatically injected `<script>` tag, e.g.:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    [ ... ]
    <title>React App</title>
    <script defer="defer" src="/static/js/main.08612527.js"></script>
    <link href="/static/css/main.073c9b0a.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
<div id="root"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

*Also note that if you run `react-scripts.js start` (instead of `react-scripts.js build`) then
the `index.html` file is created in-memory (i.e. there is no new file created in the `/build` folder),
and it is also slightly different (as you can see if you inspect the source code in the browser), because this "development mode" has different requirements, like hot-reloading.*

#### webpack

`create-react-app` uses [webpack](https://webpack.js.org), and the injection of the `index.html` probably involves [this part of the `webpack.config.js`](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/main/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js#L607):

```
plugins: [
    // Generates an `index.html` file with the <script> injected.
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin( ...
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the detailed explanation! Sould we always keep the defer or would it also be possible/necessary to change the attribute to async?

Comment: @Sam if you understand this you should mark this as accpeted answer.

Comment: regarding `defer` vs. `async`, please ask a separate question for that. (I assume the `defer` should not be changed, but I don't know for sure)